# Evaluate while loop at certain point?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, conditional-statements

Is there a certain way I can check if a while loop condition is still true inside of the loop in Python? Something like this:

```
i = 0
while i < 2:
    i = 2
    evalcond
    print("This executes because the condition is still true at this point")
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Looks like you want a `while 1:` and `if:... break` structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?

```
i = 0
while i < 2:
    i = 2
    if i >= 2:
        break
    print("This executes because the condition is still true at this point")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using `break` you can also do this

```
i = 0
while i < 2:
    i = 2
    if i < 2:
        print("This executes because the condition is still true at this point")
```